# Detecting the right character encoding in PHP?

Tags: php, character-encoding, detection, multibyte

I'm trying to detect the character encoding of a string but I can't get the right result.
For example:

```
$str = "&euro; &sbquo; &fnof; &bdquo; &hellip;" ;
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'Windows-1252' ,'HTML-ENTITIES') ;
// Now $str should be a Windows-1252-encoded string.
// Let's detect its encoding:
echo mb_detect_encoding($str,'Windows-1252, ISO-8859-1, UTF-8') ;
```

That code outputs `ISO-8859-1` but it should be `Windows-1252`.

What's wrong with this?

**EDIT:**
Updated example, in response to @raina77ow.

```
$str = "&euro;&sbquo;&fnof;&bdquo;&hellip;" ; // no white-spaces
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'Windows-1252' ,'HTML-ENTITIES') ;
$str = "Hello $str" ; // let's add some ascii characters
echo mb_detect_encoding($str,'Windows-1252, ISO-8859-1, UTF-8') ;
```

I get the wrong result again.

Comment: What is the PHP version you are using? It shows correctly here http://codepad.viper-7.com/NfvdWm. Btw, you should always list UTF-8 first because it's the most restricted one. ISO-8859-1 is probably not needed at all because anything is valid ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @Esailija, you didn't use the code of any of the two examples in the question. Try any of the two examples and you'll get the result `ISO-8859-1`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with Windows-1252 in PHP is that it will almost *never* be detected, because as soon as your text contains any characters outside of 0x80 to 0x9f, it will not be detected as Windows-1252.

This means that if your string contains a normal ASCII letter like "A", or even a space character, PHP will say that this is not valid Windows-1252 and, in your case, fall back to the next possible encoding, which is ISO 8859-1. This is a PHP bug, see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64667.

Answer (score 0):

Although strings encoded with ISO-8859-1 and CP-1252 have different byte code representation:

```
<?php
$str = "&euro; &sbquo; &fnof; &bdquo; &hellip;" ;
foreach (array('Windows-1252', 'ISO-8859-1') as $encoding)
{
    $new = mb_convert_encoding($str, $encoding, 'HTML-ENTITIES');
    printf('%15s: %s detected: %10s explicitly: %10s',
        $encoding,
        implode('', array_map(function($x) { return dechex(ord($x)); }, str_split($new))),
        mb_detect_encoding($new),
        mb_detect_encoding($new, array('ISO-8859-1', 'Windows-1252'))
    );
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Results:

```
Windows-1252: 802082208320842085 detected:            explicitly: ISO-8859-1
  ISO-8859-1: 3f203f203f203f203f detected:      ASCII explicitly: ISO-8859-1
```

...from what we can see here it looks like there is problem with second paramater of `mb_detect_encoding`. Using `mb_detect_order` instead of parameter yields very similar results.

Comment: The characters in the example don't exist in ISO-8859-1.

Comment: The first matching encoding in my list is `Windows-1252`. `ISO-8859-1` is the second in the list.

Comment: @GetFree php strings are not characters but bytes. Any PHP string is valid `ISO-8859-1` because any byte is valid ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @Esailija, what about `Windows-1252`? Is any byte valid `Windows-1252` too? If that were the case then `ISO-8859-1` and `Windows-1252` would be the same?

Comment: @GetFree no, Windows-1252 has 5 holes. Although if none of these holes are present in the target text, then W1252 and ISO-8859-1 are indistinguishable for `mb_detect_encoding`. Although nobody uses ISO-8859-1. When they say they do, they are actually using Windows-1252.

Comment: I disagree. There are quite some people, especially in the Unix world, that really use ISO 8859-1 and _not_ Windows-1252.